# Shorthand if/else statement without assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to shorthand a block like this?

```
if (popupIsvisible === false) {
    this.show();
} else {
    this.hide();
}
```

I've tried:

```
popupIsvisible === false? this.show() : this.hide();
```

but I get the error below:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

I don't want to assign to something just execute the hide/show depending on `popupIsvisible`.

Comment: no meaning at all.

Comment: That's a [_style_ problem](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions), the code does work. `this[popupIsvisible ? "show" : "hide"]()`, maybe, but why are you trying to jam that code into one line?

Comment: Are you hit with a chronic shortage of lines due to Covid as well…?

Comment: This error is from `create-react-app`, right? It's not a javascript error as such

Comment: @Stuart it's from ESLint possibly via CRA, yes.

Comment: yes, is from eslint. I thought that is better to use shorthand any time is possible :) So is better to leave it as if / else ?

Comment: It's more readable and adaptable *not* to use the shorthand, so this seems like a useful rule to enforce. In normal javascript development you could just ignore the eslint style warning. If you really want to use it in your react app, you could change your eslint configuration to allow it.

Comment: you could prepend with `void`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe many thanks! this[popupIsvisible ? "show" : "hide"]() is working well. But what you suggest? Is it better to keep the if / else statement instead this short one line ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no! there is no way to do that as you want

but you you can just do this however I see no point doing that

```
if (popupIsvisible) this.show();
else this.hide();
```

Comment: As I commented above there _are_ ways to do that. If their style guide prohibits unused expressions it might just as well prohibit brace-less blocks.

Comment: Thank you guys for you interest and help! It's working without braces but I thought that using ternary operator will be a better implementation

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes that's might be the case but apparently it worked for him, your solution works too